# Multistep method. Zero-stable

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ be some fixed parameters. Show that the multistep methods described by $\rho(z)=(z-1)(\alpha{z}+1-\alpha)$, $\sigma(z)=(z-1)^2b+(z-1)a+\frac{(z+1)}{2}$ are of order $2$，and show that they are zero-stable if and only if $\alpha\ge\frac{1}{2}$.

Please help me with this question. It really confuses me.

I have computed out the method. It is $ay_{n+2}+(1-2a)y_{n+1}+(a-1)y_n=h(bf(x_{n+2},y_{n+2})+(a-2b+\frac{1}{2})f(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})+(a-1)f(x_n,y_n))$

Comment: Do you understand that the method encoded here is $$αy_{n+1}+y_n+(1-α)y_{n-1}=h[bf(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})+(a-2b+0.5)f(t_n,y_n)-(a+b-0.5)f(t_{n-1},y_{n-1})]?$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I could understand this step.

Comment: Now for zero-stability you only need that the root of $(αz+1−α)$ is inside the unit circle.

Comment: Oh got it. Thank you very much! It is root condition. Could you please tell me what is meant by ‘every zero that lies on the unit circle is simple’. What is the meaning of simple? Does it mean single?

Comment: It means that is has multiplicity 1.

Comment: So we already a root that lies on the unit circle. Then the root of $\alpha z+1-\alpha$ cannot be on the unit circle? But the question says iff $\alpha$ is larger than or equal to 1/2

Comment: And do I need to prove the Lipschitz condition?

Comment: Yes, you can include the weakly stable case. The Lipschitz condition is a property that comes with $f$, not from the method.

Comment: But if I include the weakly stable case, the multiplicity of the root that lies on the unit circle will not be 1...

Comment: I do not see how, the second root would be at $-1$, with multiplicity $1$.

Comment: But is it the case that -1 is also on the unit circle?

Comment: Yes, but it is a different simple root on the unit circle. The problem is that resonance at a multiple root would destroy the stability. This is obviously not a problem for roots strictly inside the unit circle, as then `n*z^n` converges to zero eventually.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very clear!

Comment: There is still something that confused me. In the theorem, it says ‘a linear multi-step method is zero-stable for any ODE y’(x)=f(x,y) with Lipschitz right-hand side, if and only if the method satisfies the root condition.’ Do you mean that I don’t need to show f(x,y) satisfies  Lipschitz?

Comment: If you have a given ODE system, then it would be useful to confirm the Lipschitz condition. For this theorem only ODE with it are admissible.